# cURL timing out but postman works (local)

Tags: php, laravel, curl, postman

Im having an issue since I switched from XAMPP to laravel valet (windows variant)

My cURL does work in postman and returns the correct data, but the cURL request in the code now times out no matter what, its requesting on the correct URL.

```
 $url = BaseRequest::getHost();
          $curl = curl_init();
          curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
              CURLOPT_URL => $url."/locations?location=" . $loc1 . "," . $loc2,
              CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
              CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
              CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
              CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 5,
              CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
              CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
              CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
          ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);

        curl_close($curl);
        $response = json_decode($response, true);

        return $response;
```

This is for a school project where I had to build an API but for time sake its build in the same application as the front end part.

Im using Laravel 7 framework

Comment: Can you also share the Postman request you're sending (headers and url)?

Comment: `weervergelijken.test/locations?location=Heerenveen,gorredijk` the URL, and these are I assume the headers, https://gyazo.com/52a9abcb89bc26340f85de8947453726

Comment: First you need to make sure you've set up valet correctly. If you did then any *.test page should be hitting your local nginx server.

Comment: I assume if my test domains work that valet is setup correctly, the entire app is working only this one request is timing out